# Laravel Eager Loads Pagination

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eager-loading

I'm looking for a way to paginate this code. I cannot just use `->paginate()` As you see i'm using Eager Loading.

```
  return CTL_Resource::with(['creationCountry' => function($query) {
    $query->select('idCountry','name');
  }, 'creatorUser' => function($query) {
    $query->select('idUser', 'name');
  }, 'resourceType' => function($query) {
    $query->select(['idResourceType', 'name']);
  }, 'tags' => function($query) {
    $query->select(['idTag' => 'name']);
  }, 'quickTags' => function($query)  {
    $query->select(['idQuickTag' => 'name']);
  }, 'relatedTo' => function($query)  {
    $query->select(['idRelatedTo' => 'name']);
  }])->get();
```

Comment: You should be able to use paginate with eager loading. Try it.

Comment: I already tried, at least after "->get->paginate()" and instead "with()"... but cant.   I found a method here and will try  https://jenssegers.com/57/laravel-pagination-with-grouping-and-eager-loading

Comment: you dont need to use `->get()` if you are using `->paginate()`

Comment: Ohhh nice, that was my error. Sorry and thank you so much.

Comment: I've added it as an answer if you wan wish to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `->get()` if you are using `->paginate()`